# AWS cannot connect using SSH after restart server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cannot reconnect through ssh after restart the Elastic beanstalk server. I tried changing security group. Is there anyone can help me to figure this out...

Comment: Could you ssh before restart?

Comment: Yahh It worked fine. But after restart I couldn't

Comment: What change did you make to the security group? When you make changes to an environment it is possible yhat your instance gets replaced. Can you double check you are trying to ssh to the right ec2 instance?

Comment: I think Elastic beanstalk instances are terminated if they are in "shutting down" mode. The instances you may be seeing are new ones created by auto scaling group. If this is the case, IP address will be different.

Comment: RohitBanga and Rakesh Thanks for your response. I slowed it by creating new security group

Answer (score 1):

After spending couple of hours I solev this problem. I created New Security Group with the following inbound rules
**SSH port 22,HTTP port 80, and FTP port 21-22**

After that I add newly created security group to the Beanstalk Server Configuration( You can find this under **Configuration -> Instance** in your Beanstalk dashboard) .